Running a curl command via bash returned "URL rejected: Bad hostname", but works on cmdline
When I try to run this cmd via bash like this
Bash Script
mycommand="curl $mycommand --url '${requestURL}'"
echo "Search Command $mycommand"
myresponse="$(${mycommand})"

Output
Search Command curl -v -X GET --header Authorization:'Bearer ---very long access token---' -s '
https://my-rest-services:443/mypath/someparameters'
* URL rejected: Bad hostname
* Closing connection
* URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
* Closing connection

When I run the follow command on cmd line, it runs perfectly, and returns my json response
curl -v -X GET --header Authorization:'Bearer ---very long access token---' -s '
https://my-rest-services:443/mypath/someparameters'

{myjson response}


Don't store commands in variables. Variables are for data, not executable code. If you need to store executable code, use a function, or for simple commands an array. See BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!", "Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?", and many other previous questions. But ignore all suggestions to use eval, it's a massive bug magnet.

@GordonDavisson this is very good advice.. reading thru

@GordonDavisson can you give me the code snippet that will make it work without eval and also return the json that the curl returns please?

Is there a reason to store the command first. rather than just using echo "Search Command curl $mSearchCommand --url '${requestURL}'"; mSearchResponse="$(curl $mSearchCommand --url "$requestURL}")"?

I get a Search Response {"code":"401", "message":"String index out of range: -1"}

Oh, I didn't notice that $mSearchCommand also contains shell syntax (which causes the exact same problems). How is that variable set, and why is it in a variable rather than just being separate options to the actual command?

I'll refactor the code as per the advice and get back.

mSearchResponse="$(curl -v --header Authorization:'Bearer $accessTokenFromAuthResponse' --url 'https://myfullurl')" returns >>>> Accept: /

Authorization:'Bearer

< HTTP/2 401 <<<

echo on $accessTokenFromAuthResponse returns the full token.. what am I missing.. ? $accessTokenFromAuthResponse is data

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I modified my bash script to the below and it started to work. "eval" was the way to run it.
    mycommand="curl $mycommand --url '${requestURL}'"
    echo "Search Command $mycommand"
    eval "$mycommand"

Edit, as per amazing advice from @Gordon I am adding a better answer.

Use of eval is not adviced.
Do not use strings for commands, only for data

This is what I did to get things working.
function callingMyAPI {
    requestURL="$1"
    accessTokenFromAuthResponse="$2"
    #My REQUEST
    callingMyAPI=$(curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $accessTokenFromAuthResponse" $requestURL)
}

callingMyAPI "$url" $accessToken 

This worked.

Please don't use eval for things like this, it tends to solve simple problems but cause unexpected weird problems later on, in particular when unexpected shell syntax characters show up in your data -- and eval parses (and maybe executes) them as shell syntax. See "Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?"

wrapping the curl command in $(curl... ) is the solution.  Thank you!

You can just leave the eval out and unquote the final line
mycommand="curl $mycommand --url '${requestURL}'"
echo "Search Command $mycommand"
$myresponse


Did nto work curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535

The fact that you got an error message from curl actually demonstrates that it does work, but you have an error with your ${requestURL}.
